# Re-INVITE during call results with 481 Call Does Not Exist

Tags: sip, voip, telephony, freeswitch, sip-server

I've got a FreeSwitch server (1.4.26 on Ubuntu).
When redirecting an incoming call to an external server, 30 minutes after the call connected, I've getting a RE-INVITE message from the target server. My FreeSwitch server responds with "481 Call Does Not Exist" and then the call is disconnected, although it was going on nicely.

I assume the RE-INVITE is sent after half the time of "Session-Expires: 3600;refresher=uac" has passed.

I tried to tell FreeSwitch to ignore re-invites, using set sip_ignore_reinvites=true before the bridge. Didn't seem to have any effect. Tried in the bridge's originate string too. Didn't help.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Here are SIP logs (1111 call 9999):

```
send 1069 bytes to udp/[99.99.99.99]:5060 at 15:02:29.531004:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   INVITE sip:12129999999@99.99.99.99:5060 SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 55.55.55.55;rport;branch=z9hG4bKvjUSX912pUc9Q
   Max-Forwards: 67
   From: "12121111111" <sip:12121111111@55.55.55.55>;tag=p02B1veKSg0tS
   To: <sip:12129999999@99.99.99.99:5060>
   Call-ID: ATUCMSOAWBAMZGOJMMLEQ7CU74@11.11.11.48_01
   CSeq: 92276610 INVITE
   Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@55.55.55.55:5060>
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.4.26+git~20151215T154940Z~5579a4ba46~64bit
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY
   Supported: timer, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, refer
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Disposition: session
   Content-Length: 223
   X-FS-Support: update_display,send_info
   Remote-Party-ID: "12121111111" <sip:12121111111@55.55.55.55>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=off

   v=0
   o=FreeSWITCH 1465208343 1465208344 IN IP4 55.55.55.55
   s=FreeSWITCH
   c=IN IP4 55.55.55.55
   t=0 0
   m=audio 17006 RTP/AVP 0 101 13
   a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-16
   a=ptime:20
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 802 bytes from udp/[99.99.99.99]:5060 at 15:02:50.184437:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 200 OK
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 55.55.55.55;received=55.55.55.55;branch=z9hG4bKvjUSX912pUc9Q;rport=5060
   From: "12121111111" <sip:12121111111@55.55.55.55>;tag=p02B1veKSg0tS
   To: <sip:12129999999@99.99.99.99:5060>;tag=9307555045152742154
   Call-ID: ATUCMSOAWBAMZGOJMMLEQ7CU74@11.11.11.48_01
   CSeq: 92276610 INVITE
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Session-Expires: 3600;refresher=uas
   Contact: <sip:12129999999@99.99.99.99:5060;user=phone;transport=udp>
   Supported: timer,100rel
   Content-Length: 288

   v=0
   o=MG4000|2.0 193121 196925 IN IP4 99.99.99.99
   s=-
   c=IN IP4 99.99.99.99
   t=0 0
   m=audio 61308 RTP/AVP 0 101
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-15
   a=ptime:20
   a=X-vrzcap:vbd Ver=0 Mode=FaxPr ModemRtpRed=0
   a=X-vrzcap:identification bin=DSR2883 Prot=mgcp App=MG
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 934 bytes from udp/[99.99.99.99]:5060 at 15:32:50.190171:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   INVITE sip:mod_sofia@55.55.55.55:5060 SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 99.99.99.99:5060;branch=z9hG4bKi8jups3010shhe7um2g0sb0000g00.1
   Call-ID: ATUCMSOAWBAMZGOJMMLEQ7CU74@11.11.11.48_01
   From: <sip:12129999999@99.99.99.99:5060>;tag=9307555045152742154
   To: "12121111111" <sip:12121111111@55.55.55.55>;tag=p02B1veKSg0tS
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Min-SE: 90
   Session-Expires: 3600;refresher=uac
   CSeq: 1 INVITE
   Contact: <sip:12129999999@99.99.99.99:5060;user=phone;transport=udp>
   Allow: INVITE,CANCEL,BYE,ACK,REFER,UPDATE,INFO,PRACK
   Supported: timer,100rel
   Max-Forwards: 69
   User-Agent: VCS 5.10.2.10-02
   Content-Length: 288

   v=0
   o=MG4000|2.0 193121 196925 IN IP4 99.99.99.99
   s=-
   c=IN IP4 99.99.99.99
   t=0 0
   m=audio 61308 RTP/AVP 0 101
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-15
   a=ptime:20
   a=X-vrzcap:vbd Ver=0 Mode=FaxPr ModemRtpRed=0
   a=X-vrzcap:identification bin=DSR2883 Prot=mgcp App=MG
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 513 bytes to udp/[99.99.99.99]:5060 at 15:32:50.190379:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 481 Call Does Not Exist
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 99.99.99.99:5060;branch=z9hG4bKi8jups3010shhe7um2g0sb0000g00.1
   From: <sip:12129999999@99.99.99.99:5060>;tag=9307555045152742154
   To: "12121111111" <sip:12121111111@55.55.55.55>;tag=p02B1veKSg0tS
   Call-ID: ATUCMSOAWBAMZGOJMMLEQ7CU74@11.11.11.48_01
   CSeq: 1 INVITE
   User-Agent:FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.4.26+git~20151215T154940Z~5579a4ba46~64bit
   Allow:INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL,OPTIONS,MESSAGE,INFO,UPDATE,REGISTER,REFER,NOTIFY
   k:timer,path,replaces
   l:0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 374 bytes from udp/[99.99.99.99]:5060 at 15:32:50.276999:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ACK sip:mod_sofia@55.55.55.55:5060 SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 99.99.99.99:5060;branch=z9hG4bKi8jups3010shhe7um2g0sb0000g00.1
   CSeq: 1 ACK
   Call-ID: ATUCMSOAWBAMZGOJMMLEQ7CU74@11.11.11.48_01
   From: <sip:12129999999@99.99.99.99:5060>;tag=9307555045152742154
   To: "12121111111" <sip:12121111111@55.55.55.55>;tag=p02B1veKSg0tS
   Max-Forwards: 69
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 477 bytes from udp/[99.99.99.99]:5060 at 15:32:50.290275:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   BYE sip:mod_sofia@55.55.55.55:5060 SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 99.99.99.99:5060;branch=z9hG4bKi8jups3010shhe7um2g0sd0000010.1
   Call-ID: ATUCMSOAWBAMZGOJMMLEQ7CU74@11.11.11.48_01
   From: <sip:12129999999@99.99.99.99:5060>;tag=9307555045152742154
   To: "12121111111" <sip:12121111111@55.55.55.55>;tag=p02B1veKSg0tS
   CSeq: 2 BYE
   Supported: timer,100rel
   Max-Forwards: 69
   Reason: SIP;cause=0;iintcode=516;isubsystem=0
   User-Agent: VCS 5.10.2.10-02
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 510 bytes to udp/[99.99.99.99]:5060 at 15:32:50.290421:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 481 Call Does Not Exist
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 99.99.99.99:5060;branch=z9hG4bKi8jups3010shhe7um2g0sd0000010.1
   From: <sip:12129999999@99.99.99.99:5060>;tag=9307555045152742154
   To: "12121111111" <sip:12121111111@55.55.55.55>;tag=p02B1veKSg0tS
   Call-ID: ATUCMSOAWBAMZGOJMMLEQ7CU74@11.11.11.48_01
   CSeq: 2 BYE
   User-Agent:FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.4.26+git~20151215T154940Z~5579a4ba46~64bit
   Allow:INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL,OPTIONS,MESSAGE,INFO,UPDATE,REGISTER,REFER,NOTIFY
   k:timer,path,replaces
   l:0
```

Answer (score 1):

If the above is the whole trace it is strange that now ACK is sent from FS after the 200. The re-invite is as you say a session refresh which happens on the same dialog but it is a different transaction.

Looking at the Call Id from-tag / to-tag the re-invite looks correct.

Make a tcpdump / wireshark and make sure the Re-invite is sent to the correct port and that there is an ACK after 200 ok for the initial invite

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to turn on RFC 4028 support on Freeswitch?

https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Sofia.conf.xml#SIP_Related_options

In your sip profile:

```
<param name="enable-timer" value="true"/>
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the default for this parameter was "true", since I did see that "timers" is supported in the INVITE.
I did try to disable it, which actually helped in some cases. "timers" is no longer there.
Another trick that seems to help: I've set <param name="session-timeout" value="1500"/>, which is shorter than when I'm getting from the remote site. This causes MY server to send a RE-INVITE and I'm getting OK from the remote and the call goes on.

Comment: When you set <param name="session-timeout" value="1500"/> then it probably changes enable-timer to "true" from "false", because there is no point for timer if feature is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the to tag (tag=p02B1veKSg0tS) in the re-invite as this is a new transaction.

Comment: The re-invite is sent to my server from the remote server. How can I remove the tag if I'm not the one sending this SIP message?
Also, this IS the same transaction, with the same tag. Why does the FS server claims it doesn't exist?

Comment: I was thinking that it is your own client. Otherwise it is not the same transaction and for new transaction (initiated by the reINVITE) the to tag should not be set. Check the same with some other softhone and if that works, then you can confirm that this was caused the problem.